# Launchpad PPA for Jammy does not have release file, cannot update on 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, ppa, update-manager

When trying to `sudo apt-get update` this is the output:

```
[sudo] password for bobert: 
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease               
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease            
Ign:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease   
Err:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done                              
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I am a little confused on how to fix this as it looks to be my only PPA, other than the same thing with (source code) at the end of it.

Because it is my only PPA, the software & updates app will freeze up if I try to modify it in any way.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file). You don't need *any* PPAs and the default system contains none, so that doesn't explain the software and updates app freezing. I suggest you remove the PPA using the command line as indicated in the duplicate.

Comment: Oh I see. I actually do not know where that PPA came from. I was able to use [this](https://itsfoss.com/how-to-remove-or-delete-ppas-quick-tip/) to remove the ppa without uninstalling whatever app was using it, using method 3. And my apologies, I did not realize that Ubuntu does not use any ppas by default. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Right now there appear to be 23 applications supported on the teejee2008 repo, but the repo itself is not signed for Ubuntu 22.04 and will not work with it right now.  https://github.com/teejee2008?tab=repositories  My guess is something was installed before like `ukuu` being the Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility